# Spring MVC open index.jsp on "/"

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

How can I open index.jsp using this url `http://localhost:8080/myApp/`and how can I use an hyperlink like this 
`<a href="/">HOME</a>` and go to index.jsp (`http://localhost:8080/myApp/`)?

Here's my web.xml:

```
<display-name>myApp</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here is my myApp-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.myApp.com" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add a `@Controller` with an appropriate handler method

```
@Controller
public class RootController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String root() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

assuming `index.jsp` is in `/WEB-INF/view`.

Comment: It works if a put in the url http://localhost:8080/myApp/ but not on the hyperlink

Comment: @user3476247 In a hyperlink, the single `/` means an absolute path relative to the host. That means it will do `localhost:8080/`, not `localhost:8080/myapp`. You need to provide the context path either directly or dynamically with `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`.

Comment: Problem solved. But now you make me wonder why my <a href="about">ABOUT</a> element doesn't need the context path :D

Comment: @user3476247 Because there is no preceding `/`. So when the browser generates the path to send the request to, it considers that value as relative to your current URL, replacing the last path element with your value. So `href="somepath/more"` when you're at at `localhost:8080/myapp/users/admins`, the browser will send the request to `localhost:8080/myapp/users/somepath/more`.