# Spring boot showing status instead of index

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

So I updated to a newer version of Spring (now using `1.5.8` from `1.3.0.M2`).

Now when I go to the `/` mapping it shows the Spring status page:

[image]

All other mappings work fine, it seems the root mapping doesn't work well, as if it's being overriden somewhere.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public ModelAndView index() {
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}
```

This was actually returning "index.jsp" before but now is showing me the above page.

Any guidance on what to do to get my main `/` mapping back to `index.jsp`?

Comment: @JBNizet typo, see edit.

Comment: Ah, OK. Nevermind, then.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring MVC open index.jsp on "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745704/spring-mvc-open-index-jsp-on). I guess this has been answered in the above link where it says we need to define the method signature in the @RequestMapping something like this @RequestMapping(value="/", method = Requestmethod."GET")

Comment: If you look at the code I posted that's exactly what I'm already doing. Furthermore, not providing a method in the `@RequestMapping` will make it map to any HTTP request. So I would still expect a jsp page rather than Springs status page.

Answer (score 0):

have you added this two lines to your property file

```
# view resolver--------------------------------------
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are spring boot endpoints. [check here for more](http://infohttps://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints)

> By default, all endpoints except for shutdown are enabled. If you
>   prefer to specifically “opt-in” endpoint enablement you can use the
>   endpoints.enabled property. For example, the following will disable
>   all endpoints except for info:

```
endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.info.enabled=true
```